# Is there a stable version of Julia & Atom combination to install with the instructions?

Tags: installation, error-handling, julia, atom-editor

I am facing a bunch of problems with Julia on Atom editor due to neverending problems such as FFMPEG, MbedTLS, etc. I googled a lot to find how other people solve such problems by deleting and installing again, or reinstalling the packages for julia. I updated even Atom, but it didn't work. Most of the people who faced the problem do not provide the solution.

So I assume that there must be a stable combination of all packages that work properly (probably someone has tested it already). Are there any recommendations?

I understand that it is an opensource software thus there might be no answer (this is a typical answer by the community), however, if there is anyone who can share the solution or instructions that lead to correct installation and proper operation of julia I would greatly appreciate your efforts. Thanks a lot.

PS: I am using OS Windows 10, Julia 1.2.0, Atom 1.53.0 x64, julia-client 0.12.6, uber-juno 0.3.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit your question to include error traces/messages that you encountered so far? Briefly describing the steps you've already taken might help too.

Comment: Basically, Atom Juno is not supported any more - the VS Code is the recommended editor. Even worse - perhaps some will not work with Julia 1.2 because they use features introduced in later versions. Can you upgrade your programming stack?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by installing Julia 1.5.3 for Atom 1.53.0 x64 on Windows 10.
I also updated the powershell.